# how to customize the dojo tooltip label

Tags: css, dojo, tooltip

[image]

I need to add the tooltip foe dojo widget like this. But dojo tooltip shows the their own style. I need to customize the my given style.Refer the picture. How do that using css or any other else.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS, provide your own styling over-riding the styles in dijit/themes/dijit.css

for example the default container styling is

```
.dijitTooltipContainer {
    border: solid black 2px;
    background: #b8b5b5;
    color: black;
    font-size: small;
 }
```